# R: use icons instead of labels in a treemap

Tags: r, treemap

I want to replace the labels in a treemap by icons. For example, in the dummy data below, I want to replace the labels by state flag. Is this possible to implement in R using the treemap package or any other package?

```
library(treemap)

my_data=rbind(data.frame(state="CA",Car=c(6,8,5)),
           data.frame(state="FL",Car=c(5,6,4)),
           data.frame(state="NY",Car=c(10,5,0)),
           data.frame(state="CT",Car=c(10,5,5)),
           data.frame(state="MD",Car=c(7,7,8)))


 treemap(my_data, 
    index="state",
    vSize="Car",
    vColor = "Car",
    type="value",
    border.col ="white",
    title="",
    title.legend="",
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Only a partial answer but might be of some use.

If you save the output of the treemap function as an object, you can access the coordinates, width and height of the rectangles and re-use them yourself in ggplot like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(treemap)

my_data=rbind(data.frame(state="CA",Car=c(6,8,5)),
              data.frame(state="FL",Car=c(5,6,4)),
              data.frame(state="NY",Car=c(10,5,0)),
              data.frame(state="CT",Car=c(10,5,5)),
              data.frame(state="MD",Car=c(7,7,8)))


obj <- treemap(my_data, 
        index="state",
        vSize="Car",
        vColor = "Car",
        type="value",
        border.col ="white",
        title="",
        title.legend="",
)


obj$tm %>%
  mutate(x1 = x0 + w,
         y1 = y0 + h,
         xcentre = (x0 + x1) / 2,
         ycentre = (y0 + y1) / 2) %>%
  ggplot(aes(xmin = x0, ymin = y0, xmax = x1, ymax = y1, fill = vColor, x = xcentre, y = ycentre, label = state)) +
  geom_rect(colour = "white") +
  geom_text(colour = "white") +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Now your problem is just to replace that `geom_text()` with something that places the flags at `(xcentre, ycentre)` instead.  baptiste;s [`ggflags` package](https://github.com/baptiste/ggflags) would do this but it is currently out of sync with `ggplot2`.  So your options are updating `ggflags`  (or asking baptiste very nicely to do it) or various clunky work arounds.

**Edit** - You'll want to check the aspect ratio, and whether it's the right thing to use `coord_equal` or not.  This is left as an exercise for the reader.